# Can I include other students' master thesis in the literature review of my master thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, masters, literature-review

Can I include other students' master thesis in the literature review of my master thesis? These master thesis that I found are published in Google Scholar and other online libraries/archives.

Comment: Your user name is fun, of course, and I don't recommend changing it, but to some here it might be bait. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Buffy thanks! haha I know, I named it out of frustration I had on StackOverflow where people kept downvoting my questions no matter how accurate or detailed I tried to be.

Comment: I'm a bit curious why there would be hesitation doing so @dontdownvoteme.

Comment: Yes of course you can. Sometimes they must be cited in articles as well.

Comment: @Aruralreader that's because in the past projects of my master degree we have used other students' reports as "Related Work" and now I was confused if this is considered a Related work or Literature review.

Comment: @dontvotemedown, thanks, I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it might be *essential* to do so. Especially if you draw on or extend their work. You need to cite anything you use, of course.

Moreover, a literature review, if it is to be complete may need to draw on things that are "visible" even if not formally published. You may, however, need to make it clear that some such things haven't been peer reviewed so the reader needs to take some caution in accepting their results.

Answer (score 2):

If the thesis is relevant, then yes, you can certainly include it. If the thesis disseminates important and original findings on the topic you are surveying, then you should definitely include it.

I once read a peer-reviewed book-chapter by a professor that cited a master's thesis (the thesis was neither by the professor himself nor by a superstar).